# Docker Mysql container fails with “unknown database” error (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm facing a repeated issue on Ubuntu server after every couple of hours now. Mysql container suddenly gives "Uknown database" error. I'm using cron scripts (running every minute) from php container to parse blockchain and saving only block numbers in Mysql (other data goes to bigQuery). Crons finish well in time in first half second.

Could someone mention the reason? Why it's happening so? Thanks!

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'
    services:
        mysql:
            container_name: mysql_test
            image: mysql:8.0
            restart: on-failure
            environment:
                MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
                MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
                MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
                MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            ports:
                - "3306:3306"
            volumes:
                - ../docker_volumes/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
                - ./docker/mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

        php:
            container_name: php_test
            build: ./docker/php
            tty: true
            volumes:
                - ./:/var/www/
                - ./docker/volumes/symfony/var/data:/var/www/var/data
                - ./docker/volumes/symfony/var/log:/var/www/var/log
            depends_on:
                - mysql
```

Sample screenshot from `docker stats mysql_test` [image]

Comment: please provide the dockerfile/docker-compose , so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

- This issue is auto fixed after I changed mysql default `root` password
- Another possible solution could be disabling remote access by setting `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in my.cnf